# How to change time zone in google Cloud Run

Tags: google-cloud-platform, timezone, google-cloud-run

Our cloud run time zone is GMT by default, I need to change the time zone to BST. Is there a way to change the time zone in the google cloud run?

Comment: I don't believe from my knowledge that there is a way to configure the time zone for a Cloud Run instance. Is there a specific use case you are trying to solve? For most cases you can grab the time in Cloud Run and just convert it into the time zone of your liking.

Comment: Hi @JackWotherspoon, I think you are right, we can't change the time zone in the cloud run. we have to run the scheduler script based on the regions. so.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can change the container localtime like this

```
FROM ubuntu
RUN apt-get update && DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get -y install tzdata
RUN rm /etc/localtime && ln -s /usr/share/zoneinfo/America/Los_Angeles /etc/localtime
```

---

**EDIT 1**

Here my test code.

*main.go*

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "net/http"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    http.HandleFunc("/", Date)
    http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil)
}

func Date(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    fmt.Println(time.Now())
    fmt.Fprint(w, time.Now())
}
```

*Dockerfile*

```
FROM golang:1.17 AS builder

# Set necessary environmet variables needed for our image
ENV GO111MODULE=on \
    CGO_ENABLED=0 \
    GOOS=linux \
    GOARCH=amd64

# Move to working directory /build
WORKDIR /build

# Copy the code into the container
COPY . .

# Build the application
RUN go build -o main .

FROM ubuntu

COPY --from=builder /build/main /
RUN apt-get update && DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get -y install tzdata
RUN rm /etc/localtime && ln -s /usr/share/zoneinfo/America/Los_Angeles /etc/localtime

ENTRYPOINT ["/main"]
```

*deploy, curl command and result*

```sh
gcloud run deploy --source=. --platform=managed --region=us-central1 --allow-unauthenticated changetimezone
curl https://changetimezone-<hash>-uc.a.run.app

-> Result: 
2022-04-12 06:32:40.688742034 -0700 PDT m=+0.069703450
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried to change the time zone in the container level, but when I checked the logs from the cloud run, it's still showing the GMT time zone. (2022-04-12 09:41:45.174 BST - 2022-04-12 08:41:45.173 DEBUG  (1 hr difference))

Comment: Just tested in Go, and it works great. I can share the code if you want.

Comment: yes, guillaume blaquiere, please.

Comment: Done. I'm located in France. The Los Angeles Timezone is the correct one.

Comment: Thanks guillaume blaquiere, it worked.